# FFMPEG: Creating video using drawtext along with word wrap and padding

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm working to create a video from text with drawtext filter. Output video i can see the text is overflowing instead of coming in new line.

Is there any way i can archive word wrapping and also set the internal padding to video?

*Below is the snippet I'm using to generate video from text*

```
ffmpeg.exe -f lavfi -i color=c=white:s=640x480:d=5.396 -vf "[in] drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:fontsize=20:fontcolor=black:x=0+0*print(tw):y=0+0*print(th):text='this is new whiteboard te':enable='between(t,6.634,6.818)',drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:fontsize=20:fontcolor=black:x=0+0*print(tw):y=0+0*print(th):text='this is new whiteboard testing':enable='between(t,0.0,2.032)',drawtext=fontfile=font.ttf:fontsize=20:fontcolor=black:x=0+0*print(tw):y=0+0*print(th):text='this is new whiteboard testing no padding and the text is overflowing from the video frame check this  need to acheve word wrapping':enable='between(t,2.032,5.396)'"[out] -c:v libx264 -t 30 -crf 30 ../output.mp4
```

**Output looks like this**
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Use the [subtitles filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) instead.

[image]

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i color=c=white:s=640x480:d=5 -vf "subtitles=subs.srt" output.mp4
```

You can generate ASS or SRT subtitles manually or via Aegisub.

Example SRT:

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:05,000
This is new whiteboard testing no padding and the text is overflowing from the video frame check this  need to acheve word wrapping.
```

ASS files are more complicated structurally, but they allow more formatting options. Otherwise, you can use the `force_style` option in the subtitles filter. Search this site for several examples.

Comment: Subtitles filter is not working in my case because I cannot generate the `srt` file in advance, my captions are generated from a live stream audio and I am live streaming it back with subtitles.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to use `subtitle` filter for any reason, you can still draw text over multiple line using `drawtext`.

Just split the text into lines of a certain length (20 characters, you can set according to your need) before passing to `ffmpeg`.

```py
def split_txt_into_multi_lines(input_str: str, line_length: int):
    words = input_str.split(" ")
    line_count = 0
    split_input = ""
    for word in words:
        line_count += 1
        line_count += len(word)
        if line_count > line_length:
            split_input += "\n"
            line_count = len(word) + 1
            split_input += word
            split_input += " "
        else:
            split_input += word
            split_input += " "
    
    return split_input
        
inp = "This is new whiteboard testing no padding and the text is overflowing from the video frame check this  need to acheve word wrapping."
length = 20 
new_input = split_txt_into_multi_lines(inp,length)
```