# FFMPEG : Drawtext filter with word wrapping support

Tags: ffmpeg, drawtext

I need to draw max two line text at top of some backgroud. I need to wrap that text if that is longer. Text will be horizontal center align.

I have tried and use DrawText filter but not able to find way to use text wrap automatically.

Some developers suggesting to use subtitle but this is not related to video so I want to check with Drawtext if possible.
[Draw text using Subtitle filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50628267/ffmpeg-creating-video-using-drawtext-along-with-word-wrap-and-padding)

Can someone please guide how we can achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Use subtitle filter. Set starting time to 0.

Comment: Thanks @Gyan for your reply. I had found solution using Subtitle filter but I wanted to do this using Drawtext. Is this possible using Drawtext filter?

Comment: Not implemented.