# how to prevent long text going out of video bounds?

Tags: swift, video, ffmpeg

i am adding text to video using ffmpeg.

```
var filterComplex = ""
for (index, textData) in textDataArray.enumerated() {
     print("x: \(textData.xPosition), y: \(textData.yPosition)")
     let x = (textData.xPosition * 1080) / videoViewWidth
     let y = (textData.yPosition * 1920) / videoViewHeight
                                    
     let fontSizeForWidth = (20 * 1080) / videoViewWidth
     let fontSizeForHeight = (20 * 1920) / videoViewHeight
     print("fontSizeForWidth: \(fontSizeForWidth)")
     print("fontSizeForHeight: \(fontSizeForHeight)")
                                    
     if index == textDataArray.count - 1 {
         let textFilter = "[video\(index)]drawtext=text='\(textData.text)':fontfile=\(fontPath):fontsize=\(fontSizeForHeight):fontcolor=white:x=(main_w-text_w-\(x)):y=(\(y)-(text_h/2))"
          filterComplex += textFilter
     } else {
          let textFilter = "[video\(index)]drawtext=text='\(textData.text)':fontfile=\(fontPath):fontsize=\(fontSizeForHeight):fontcolor=white:x=(main_w-text_w-\(x)):y=(\(y)-(text_h/2))[video\(index + 1)];"
          filterComplex += textFilter
     }
                                    
}
```

this is my code to add drawtext to command. now my problem is if text is longer it is going out of video bounds instead i want it to be at same x y positons but i want to convert it to multiple lines.

i have seen some solutions where they are telling me to add \n to my text but i am getting it from user and i am not able to determine that where to add \n so this solution is not working for me. if possible tell me how to change x y so that i can manage this or any other solutions if more effective.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FFMPEG: Creating video using drawtext along with word wrap and padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50628267/ffmpeg-creating-video-using-drawtext-along-with-word-wrap-and-padding)

Comment: @HangarRash No I have already seen that but I want to add text to specific positions and in multiple lines. for now, I am getting the x position in minus (-) so the text is going out of video from left.